# Is it possible to have a square root as an exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to have a square root as an exponent? If so, how do we solve such math problems?

Example such as the two math problems below:

$$\huge 7^{\sqrt{8}} \qquad\qquad \frac1{25^{\sqrt{2}}}$$

Comment: Well, it is indeed POSSIBLE but the answer woud be an irrational number.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes, any real number can be an exponent. But, it's not clear what it means to "solve" the expressions you've written. $7^{\sqrt{8}}$ is a real number, that is all. You could try to compute its decimal digits (not easy without a calculator), but I don't know what it would mean to "solve" $7^{\sqrt{8}}$. Those are not math problems, those are just numbers that are written down.

Comment: As @littleO mentioned, any real number can be an exponent, be it $\sqrt{2}$, $e^{e}$, or even $\pi$, but remember that $0^{0}$ is an exception.

Comment: Yes it is possible and it can be computed: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5Esqrt%288%29

Comment: If you want to know the value of these expressions your best bet is to use logarithm.

Comment: You can even have $\sqrt[\sqrt{2}]{2}=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, irrational exponents can represent the sum of infinite rational numbers.

Therefore,

If, $\alpha >0, b≥0,  a_k\in\mathbb Q^{+}$ for every $k\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ and

$$\begin{align} &\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k=\sqrt \alpha,~ \sqrt {\alpha}\in {\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q} &\end{align}$$ then

$$\begin{align}b^{\sqrt \alpha}=b^{a_1}\times b^{a_2}\times \cdots \times b^{a_n}\times \cdots\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Take the example $2^\sqrt{2}$. To calculate it, we use an approximation for $\sqrt{2}$ like $1.414$ and replace it. So, you get $2^{1.414}$ which becomes $\sqrt[1000]{2^{1414}}$, which you can easily calculate.

Comment: By the way we can't  easily evaluate $\sqrt[1000]{2^{1414}}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Easier in comparison to evaluating an irrational exponent that is